# Correct way of loading SSL certificate signed by Intermediate CA in Kestrel .NET Core

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, x509certificate, kestrel

I am setting up SSL on my Kestrel Linux server using .NET Core 2.1.1.

The SSL certificate is signed by an **intermediate** CA.

The PFX contains the intermediate and root CA cert.

I load the pfx file as a X509Certificate2 object and use this for the server certificate.

It seems to be that the way I have set this up, the intermediate CA is not sent as part of the handshake and only the leaf is sent (this is very naughty).

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any,443, listenOptions =>
                {

                    listenOptions.UseHttps("ssl.pfx", "password123");

                });
            }
            )
        .Build();
```

So I execute this command and it shows only the leaf but not the intermediate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myserver:443
```

I expect it to include the intermediate ca and leaf as one would expect like this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this very recently and found that the server (debian in this case) hosting the web service required explicit trust in the intermediate cert in addition to the root cert.  Without this, it would only send the subject cert, but when I added the intermediate directly to the trust, it started working correctly.

Comment: That is certainly letting communication happen but it's actually weird to do it this way.  The PFX includes everything needed and so, one should not need to manually add the intermediate(s) and root cert to the "store"!

Comment: Yes, you're 100% correct.  The only thing you should need in your root trust is the root certificate itself.  The intermediate should be included with the subject certs and served up by the webserver.  

[This turned out to be a bug in Kestrel:](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10971)

Answer (score 2):

.NET 8 sample program on sending the certificate chain as part of the HTTPS handshake.

```cs
// Program.cs

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((_, serverOptions) =>
{
    var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("certs/server-certificate.crt", "certs/server-certificate.key");
    serverOptions.ListenLocalhost(7000, listenOptions => listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate, httpsConnectionAdapterOptions =>
    {
        var x509Certificate2Collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        x509Certificate2Collection.ImportFromPemFile("certs/ca-chain-bundle.crt");
        httpsConnectionAdapterOptions.ServerCertificateChain = x509Certificate2Collection;
    }));
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```